# Profile page don't fit 15-inch displays (laptops) when used in Opera browser

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, opera

In displays/screens with 15 inch, the profile layout doesn't fit, for example on Meta Stack Exchange:

[image: Screenshot: Bug in layout]

This "bug" occurs on the `stackoverflow.com/users/<id>` and `meta.stackexchange.com/users/<id>` pages.

On other pages the "new menu" (left menu) doesn't affect the main layout.

Resolution screen: 1280x800

> I'm aware this is due to the Opera menu and I understand that maybe it's something that will never be solved, but I'm just reporting that someone notices the same problem and does not understand why it's occurring.